# Sort algorithm swap doesn't work

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of pointers to words lexicographically and the sort itself seems to work, except of the swap, i tried many formats and i can't make it work, hope you could help me:

```
    for(i=1;i<words;i++){
        for(j=i;j>0 && strcmp(dicArray[0][j-1],dicArray[0][j]) == 1;j--){
            temp = dicArray[0][j];
            dicArray[0][j-1] = dicArray[0][j];
            dicArray[0][j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `dicArray`?  Can you show a full example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: dicArray is char** type, dicArray[0][j] contains a pointer to a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your swapping algo is not correct.
If you want to swap `dicArray[0][j-1]` and `dicArray[0][j]`, then do the following:

```
temp = dicArray[0][j];
dicArray[0][j] = dicArray[0][j-1];
dicArray[0][j-1] = temp;
```

Comment: Seems like i tried everything except looking if i wrote the swapping function correctly, thank you!